# Can't store result in session from async waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, async.js

I have a series of methods I run using async.waterfall which then return a result. I store that result into a request.session variable because I use Ajax and work with the result later on. However, I find that I can set the value of the session variable, but later on I cannot retrieve it.

Here's the code from the waterfall.

```
async.waterfall([
   //Some functions
], function(err, result) {
    request.session.cases = result;
    response.render('template.jade', {
        items : result
    });
```

I then perform a jquery load to another url which then filters cases in `request.session.cases`.
But, I find that `request.session.cases` is undefined!

```
app.get('/case/:bugid', function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.session.cases); //undefined
}
```

The weird part is that I can set `request.session.cases` to anything other than result (I can even set it to `result[0]`) and it will be fine. I've also printed out the value of result before I do the Ajax call and it is indeed populated with an array of objects.

Comment: I was using a cookieSession, which for whatever reason couldn't do that (maybe it was too large). I changed to using session and now it's fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cookieSession has a very small size of data that you can store into it. The data I was trying to store was too big for a cookieSession. Therefore I switched to using a session for that type of data, and using a normal cookie for user login.